# Eclipse Android - when i choose text icon it does not create project

Tags: java, android, icons, launcher

I hava a problem with an error in ADT Plugin. I want to make an Android Project Application.
When I want to set app icon I switch it to Text and then write the name X - for example. Then if i click next and finish window does not closes and a project i let's say halfly made(some packages). If i leave the icon default(not text) everything loads fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the drawable name can't contains capital letters, maybe that's the problem

Comment: Checked right now, problem stays. It does compute something last window of project wizard does not disappears and these packages are created. PS: This "aA" is automaticly generated by Eclipse.

Comment: Image works. Just text does not. The idiotic way is to printscreen generated text icon then save it as image ; /